For a function to be Riemann Integrable the set of discontinuities can be countably infinite but not dense
Is it true that for a function defined on a compact interval of the real line, if it is Riemann integrable it is possible for it to still have a countably infinite number of discontinuities, so long as they are not dense in the interval of integration?

A real function on a closed interval is Riemann integrable if and only if its set of discontinuities is a zero-measure set. See this link
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039740/example-of-riemann-integrable-f-0-1-to-mathbb-r-whose-set-of-discontinui

The set of discontinuities certainly can be dense. There is a well-known Riemann-integrable function that is continuous at precisely the irrational points in any interval $[a,b]$.
